# How to set test enviroment with a large database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm building an application with ruby on rails 4. 
It's a frontend to make searches in the database, and now I want to set the rails testing framework on it.

But the standard test enviroment reset and repopulate the test database every time, and i have lots of data, so it's not practical.

At the moment I made a local copy of the database, and overrided the db:reset task, so it won't be dropped every time.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The rails db:reset task will drop the database and set it up again. Just don't run it. Also what is you command for it?

Comment: rake test always call first test:db:prepare (don't remember the exact name), to reset the test db.

Comment: rake test: runs all tests in the test folder. You can also simply run rake as Rails will run all the tests by default. Which run rake test:db; run all tests in the test folder and resets the db. I recomend you to create a new staging, so it won't be affected by the script.